# Angularjs : ui-sref state change in url not showing submenu

Tags: angularjs, uiview, state, show-hide, ui-sref

In angularjs to show/hide dynamic submenu, I am adding and removing dynamic classes in js file. Every time when the state changes in url (i.e ui-sref={{mymenu.url}}) sub menu is not visible. If there is no state change sub menu is working properly. Can anyone please suggest.

**Html**

```
<li ng-repeat='mymenu in menuItems' ng-click="showHideMenu($event);" >
<a class="iconsize" ui-sref={{mymenu.url}}>
<i class={{mymenu.image}}></i> <strong>{{mymenu.menuName}}</strong>
<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
</a>
<ul class="submenuHide">
    <li class="" ng-repeat='submenu in mymenu.submenu'> 
        <a>{{submenu.submenuName}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
    $scope.showHideMenu = function(event) {
    var classname = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].className;
    if(classname == 'submenuHide'){
        $(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1]).removeClass('submenuHide');
        $(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1]).addClass('submenuShow');
    }else if(classname == 'submenuShow'){
        $(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1]).removeClass('submenuShow');
        $(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1]).addClass('submenuHide');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things. One, you'll need to make sure your menu is outside of the individual templates you're working with. Two, using ng-class bound to an ng-model ensures that your menu state is included in the digest cycle. This will save you the jqLite and dom parsing logic.

Here's an [example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tb3cw64gPuUKonBehyp3).

So your code might look like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a ui-sref="hello">Hello</a>
    <a ui-sref="about">About</a>
    <button ng-click="toggleMenu()">Show / Hide Menu</button>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    <ul ng-class="{showMenu: show, hideMenu: !show}">
        <li ng-repeat="letter in ['a','b','c','d']">{{letter}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

With this JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  };
});
```